# How to find all vertex-disjoint paths in a graph?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, graph-theory, shortest-path

Suppose there are 3 target nodes in a graph.

A vertex-disjoint path means there is not any same node except the end nodes during the path.

For any one single node, say node i, how to find all vertex-disjoint paths from node i to the three target nodes?

Comment: To be clear, you mean a path that starts at `i`, goes through each of the three target nodes, and then returns to `i` with no repeats except that the two ends are the same? Also, do you want to find all such paths (like you say) or the shortest such path (like it's tagged)?

Comment: In my purpose, I want to find a path starting with node i and finishing at the target node, say node z. If there are more than one path, there should have no same nodes in these paths except nodes i and node z. I hope to find all these paths from i to z.

Comment: Oh, that's very different from what I (and templatetypedef) understood. So you want to find a set of paths from `i` to `z` such that the paths are disjoint? There are potentially many such sets (depending on which of the possible paths you pick). So maybe what you want to do is find all paths from `i` to `z` (via eg breadth-first search) and then process them to find a disjoint set. One easy way to do that, which won't find the largest such set or anything: pick a path from the set, remove all other paths which intersect that path, repeat.

Comment: Of course, you could combine the two steps of that algorithm I just described. Maybe do depth-first search, and then once you've found a valid path, remove all of its nodes from the graph and continue your search. If you specify that you want some special set of disjoint paths to the target, though, there's definitely a better way. (I still don't know what you mean by there being 3 target nodes, though...just doing this 3 times, or finding paths from `i` to `x`, `y`, and `z` such that `i->x`, `i->y`, and `i->z` are disjoint?)

Comment: @Dougal , Thx a lot. Yes, your idea of depth-first and then delete them might be possible for solving this problem. And about the 3 target nodes are actually not having too much business on the algorithm. Nodes x and y are same with z, so it will just repeat the process of finding paths to z.

Answer (score 28):

You can solve this problem by reducing it to a max-flow problem in an appropriately-constructed graph.  The idea is as follows:

1. Split each node v in the graph into to nodes: v<sub>in</sub> and v<sub>out</sub>.
2. For each node v, add an edge of capacity one from v<sub>in</sub> to v<sub>out</sub>.
3. Replace each other edge (u, v) in the graph with an edge from u<sub>out</sub> to v<sub>in</sub> of capacity 1.
4. Add in a new dedicated destination node t.
5. For each of the target nodes v, add an edge from v<sub>in</sub> to t with capacity 1.
6. Find a max-flow from s<sub>out</sub> to t.  The value of the flow is the number of node-disjoint paths.

The idea behind this construction is as follows.  Any flow path from the start node s to the destination node t must have capacity one, since all edges have capacity one.  Since all capacities are integral, there exists an integral max-flow.  No two flow paths can pass through the same intermediary node, because in passing through a node in the graph the flow path must cross the edge from v<sub>in</sub> to v<sub>out</sub>, and the capacity here has been restricted to one.  Additionally, this flow path must arrive at t by ending at one of the three special nodes you've identified, then following the edge from that node to t.  Thus each flow path represents a node-disjoint path from the source node s to one of the three destination nodes.  Accordingly, computing a max-flow here corresponds to finding the maximum number of node-disjoint paths you can take from s to any of the three destinations.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Maybe my expression abt vertex-disjoint is not clear enough. For node s and node t, there is a path s->a-〉b->c->d->t, there are also another path beginning from s like s->e->f->g->h->t. In this case, this is a vertex-disjoint path. But if there is a path as s->e->f->g->d->t, this is not a vertex disjoint.

Comment: what would be the running time of this solution? O(nm) ?

Comment: @razshan Think of it this way: how much time is spent on preprocessing and how much time is spent on max flow?

Comment: hmm preprocessing looks linear in time, but finding the max-flow from s_out to to will take either O(n * m^2) or (n^2 * m) which will drive the big Oh notation. Does this seem logical?

Comment: Also for steps 1 and 2, do we have to split the sink node in to t_in and t_out as well?